# associate useragent information to phone model

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, user-agent

I wonder if there is a way how to identify the phone model from the user agent. 
on stackoverflow, there are already tons of scripts that allow testing for mobile browser...
Since the useragent gives the following information:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Mobile Safari/537.36

'GT-I9100' in that case is a Samsung Galaxy S2

Now I want to display on the website `Samsung Galaxy S2` instead of `GT-I9100`

The issue I have found is that for the `Galaxy S2` there are several codes like the above one and I assume the same is true for other models.
So I'm curious if there is a database or an easy way to make to show what phone it is?

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/mobile-phone-detection-brand-model-browser-etc

Answer (score 0):

*Please read this [post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/mobile-phone-detection-brand-model-browser-etc) for a more descriptive answer.*

You can use the [DDR Simple API](https://www.w3.org/TR/DDR-Simple-API/) which stands for *Device Descriptive  Repository*. You can also check out [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).